# SQL limit returns all results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to limit the number of results using variables I set them and its still returning all the results even though I'm setting a limit.

```
// Results Per page
$limit = 3;

// Page Number
$p=$_GET['p']=="" ? 1:$_GET['p'];
$start=($p-1)*$limit;

// Query
$sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE status = 2 ORDER BY ref LIMIT :start, :limit");
$sql->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();
$data=$sql->fetch();
?>

<section id="advert-listings">
    <div class="container page-wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-8 advert-listing">
            <?php
                print_r ($sql);
                echo $start; 
                echo $limit; 
            ?>
            <?php if ($sql->rowCount()!=0) : ?>
                <?php foreach ($adverts as $advert) : ?>
                <div class="caption">
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-moon-o"></i> Sleeps: <?= $advert['news']; ?></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> Pets: <?= $advert['header']; ?></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Ref: <?= $advert['ref']; ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see I echo the `$limit` & `$start` which return 0, 3.

It should be limiting the results to 3 starting at 0.

Comment: IIRC, you can't use bind vars for LIMIT arguments

Comment: What do the `bindValue()` calls return? If I was a betting man I'd say `false`... If you never check for errors then stuff like this will happen a lot.

Comment: The bind value is an int so it should work in a limit argument

Comment: Where is `$adverts` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres what you need to do;

You have limit and offset the wrong way around, change them to LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset

Next you need to cast your ints, add this;

```
$sql->bindValue(':limit', (int)$limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':start', (int)$start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Next, change this;

```
$data=$sql->fetch()
```

To:

```
$adverts=$sql->fetchAll()
```